# Program termination when trying to sort an array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have a `class` called `ContactInfo` and is structured as written below:

```
class ContactInfo
{
    private:
        string contactName;
        string contactNumber;

        public:
            ContactInfo()
            {
                contactName = "";
                contactNumber = "";
            }
            //setter and getters
};
```

and I have a function that creates an array of `ContactInfo` and populates it via user input. After populating the array it would be passed to another function that would sort it, the said function is written as shown below.

```
void sortListByName(ContactInfo contactList[], int listSize)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i+1; j < listSize+1; j++)
        {
            if(contactList[i].getContactName() > contactList[j].getContactName())
            {
                ContactInfo temp = contactList[j];
                contactList[i] = contactList[j];
                contactList[j] = temp;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The main method

```
int main()
{
    ...

    int n;//array size
    ContactInfo *newList = contactList(n);//populates the array.
    sortListByName(newList, n);

    ...
}
```

The problem is that the program would terminate before the sorting would happen and produce the error:

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
```

Comment: Change the following condition  `j < listSize+1` to `j < listSize` and it should work. Now you are reading data out of range.

Comment: Also check the re-implementation of `std::swap` in the inner loop to make sure it actually swaps the elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the upper bound of your inner loop. Notice that we can have `j` equal to the size of the array for the last iteration.

In C++, an array of size `N` has its elements indexed from `0` to `N-1`. In your case, you're trying to access an element past the end of the array, and are running into [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Ensure your index is within the bounds of the array.

Secondly, you should be using [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) over raw arrays wherever possible anyways.

Third, the standard library provides the [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) algorithm for you, which will almost always be faster than the bubble sort that you have implemented.

Answer (score 3):

Your error is made in sort algorithm in the last iteration.
The thing is, that in first for loop variable i goes from 0 to listSize,
and in second for loop variable j goes from i+1 to listSize+1. When variable i reaches listSize-1, variable j will start from i+1 in the second for loop. This means j=listSize, and then when you try to access contactList[j] an error is going to occur because elements of contactList start from index 0 and end with index listSize-1.

```
void sortListByName(ContactInfo contactList[], int listSize)
 {
    for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)  //it should be for(int i=0;i<listSize-1;i++)
    {
       //here is your mistake. When i = listSize-1 then j=listSize and
      // that index is out of range.
       for(int j = i+1; j < listSize+1; j++) //it should be for(int j=i+1;j<listSize;j++)
       {
        if(contactList[i].getContactName() >     contactList[j].getContactName())
        {
            ContactInfo temp = contactList[j];
            contactList[i] = contactList[j];
            contactList[j] = temp;
        }

    }
}
}
```

this is how your code should look like:

```
void sortListByName(ContactInfo contactList[], int listSize)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < listSize-1; i++)
    {
       for(int j = i+1; j < listSize; j++)
       {
            if(contactList[i].getContactName()>   contactList[j].getContactName())
            {
                ContactInfo temp = contactList[j];
                contactList[i] = contactList[j];
                contactList[j] = temp;
            }

     }
 }
```